# Rails association extension throws undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to create an Active Record anonymous association extension has the documentation explains [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Association+extensions). And I've got this models

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports do 
    def asdf
      "Hello extension"
    end
  end
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program
end
```

But when I test this on my `rails c` console I've an `undefined method` error.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
2.1.0 :001 > Program.first.reports.asdf
  Program Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `programs`.* FROM `programs`  ORDER BY `programs`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError:   Report Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `reports`.* FROM `reports` WHERE `reports`.`program_id` = 1
undefined method `asdf' for #<Report::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x000001035e0098>
    from /Users/mariowise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/mariowise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/mariowise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/mariowise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/mariowise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/mariowise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/mariowise/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I'm not trying to share the same extension between many associations, just trying to make this work through the anonymous module (block).

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried defining the asdf method inside your reports model?

Comment: Did you re-start the Rails console after making this change?

Comment: I've tried defining the asdf method inside the reports model, but it gives me the same error. Also I've re-started the rails console (xD)

Comment: can you replace `"Hello extension"` with `count` ? report back then :) stop spring,... restart the console..

Comment: Yeah the same result `undefined method`. I was trying some joins when i started.

Comment: can you try to stop the spring ?

Comment: Mmm.. dont know how to do that, rails s it is not running when I use rails c... if make any sense :S

Comment: Actually `spring` is not in my Gemfile/Gemlock

Comment: I believe I solved the issue, at least in `:development` env. I created another project in other folder with `rails new <name>` command, and test there the feature, and it worked. Then I came back to my project and test it again, and the feature start working perfect. Maybe it was bundle process, don't really know. It was really weird. I'll leave a comment if not works in production.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you retrieved many reports and called the method **asdf** on them, whereas your method **asdf** is defined for a single report.

Try this

```
  Program.first.reports.first.asdf
```

Comment: Yeah. Are you saying this should be called like `Program.first.reports.first.asdf` ?? I've test that case too.. but it should not be like this (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Association+extensions)

Comment: no.. `Program.first.reports.asdf` is valid. see [Association extensions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: @mariowise, then I figure your method asdf has to return or filter models, not just print something. Try to make it filter and return something, not necessarily useful, but valid.

Comment: as Arup Rakshit says, i've tested with returning `count` which should be valid (right?)... and the issue remains..

Comment: @mariowise If you don't have migrations  pending, then I don't know.

Comment: Yeah, no migrations pending.. Its a weird issue.. I'm start thinking in the ruby version or something. Thanks for you rapid support ;)

Comment: @mariowise it might not be possible to create new methods, but only override existing ones.